# knockout.js click binding not calling viewmodel function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want a function declared on my viewmodel to trigger when clicking a button. However the functions are not called when the button is clicked.

I have tried renaming the methods, callling them with parameters, but nothing triggers them. I know that knockout.js i loaded on the page since the showSmsPanel observable is working as expected.

MyJavascript.js

```
function AdminTilmeldingerViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.showSmsPanel = ko.observable(false);  // hidden initially

    self.cancelSend = function () {
        console.log('cancelSend');
        this.showSmsPanel(false);
    }

    self.sendSms = function () {
        console.log('sendSms');

    };

}

var vm = new AdminTilmeldingerViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

MyHtml.aspx

```
<div id="smsPanel" data-bind = "visible: showSmsPanel" class="row">

    <input type=button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: sendSms" id="btnSendSms" value="Send sms">

    <input type=button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click: cancelSend" value="Annuller">

</div>
```

I would expect the function to be called on clicking the buttons, but I dont see output logged to the console.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](https://jsbin.com/sogoban/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: I tried your code in CodePen and works (https://codepen.io/bludev/pen/PrjNEV)